# How to disable encoding in a text-editor?

Tags: linux, windows, encoding, notepad++

This is such a basic question I am surprised I could not easily find an answer to it:

I use Notepad++ to write my scripts in. Someone sent me some code for a shell script (.sh) that I could modify to suit my needs. I simply changed a small bit of text using Notepad++ (on Windows) and used FileZilla (SFTP) to upload it to my server (Debian Linux).

There were a few problems with this that it took my server admin an hour to find, namely:

- FileZilla, for whatever reason, defaults to ASCII rather than binary! (changed it to binary and removed the .sh association with ASCII)
- The permissions were wrong, chmod took care of this

Problem is it STILL did not work. To fix it my server admin simply copied the text right on the server (using vim or nano) into a new shell script file and saved that. Before he kept saying the problem was Windows (which he loves to hate on) but it seems it is the encoding that text-editors are using that is corrupting the files.

He said my text-editor encoding needs to be said to "None". However, that is not an option - only ANSI, UTF and UTS variants are options!

How can I create a shell script on Windows with *no* encoding whatsoever so that it doesn't get corrupted?

I need to be able to simply transfer the file to the server, I can't mess around with modifying it once on the server which is wholly impractical.

Comment: Read http://utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch The files are already UTF-8 and he indicated that was the problem

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch To clarify, if you know how to get UTF-8 to work here, I will take that as well, but I didn't find anything that would help me in that link.

Comment: The text editor shows _text_, but the file contains _bytes_, so you cannot save the file without an encoding! What you probably want is plain ASCII encoding, but that will not work if you have non-ASCII characters.

Comment: @rodrigo It's a three-line script, there's just text and carriage returns. But he said ASCII in FileZilla was a problem and to change that to Binary, does that not apply to ASCII here?

Comment: On the bottom right of Notepad++ you can right click on the left of the encoding "UTF-8" and click on Convert UNIX(LF) format. Be sure to change encoding to UTF-8 if it is not the case.

Comment: @InterLinked: That is another issue. FTP has the text vs binary option, that affects end-of-line style (`\n` vs `\r\n`), not character encoding.

Comment: You can use client like MobaXterm to edit your files remotely instead of using Fillezilla

Comment: @Shim-Sao The UNIX(LF) fixed it! Can you post as answer? That fixed my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix it EndOfLine and encoding on Notepad++ :

On the bottom right of Notepad++ you can right click on the left of the encoding "UTF-8" and click on Convert UNIX(LF) format. Be sure to change encoding to UTF-8 if it is not the case.

In Filezilla :

Transfert mode : auto

Comment: Personally I had better luck with Binary transfer rather than ASCII but the UNIX(LF) is the big thing, would never have thought of that...

Comment: I just write my config. I have never change transfert mode and it always work for me. I prefer edit files in SSH with MobaXterm + Notepad++ now.